# "Error: cannot find symbol" when compiling Android project using Gradle

Tags: java, android, eclipse, compiler-errors, gradle

I can't compile my Android project using Gradle because of the following errors:

```
:compileDebugJava
(...)/src/org/drzewo/openmrs/android/andromeda/dialog/DateTimeFragment.java:101: error: cannot find symbol
    public interface Callbacks extends ActivityCallbacks {
                                       ^
  symbol:   class ActivityCallbacks
  location: class DateTimeFragment
(...)/src/org/drzewo/openmrs/android/andromeda/dialog/DateTimeFragment.java:53: error: method asCallbacks in class Util cannot be applied to given types;
        mPickerOptions = Util.asCallbacks(activity, Callbacks.class).getPickerOptions();
                             ^
  required: Activity,Class<T>
  found: Activity,Class<Callbacks>
  reason: inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
    inferred: Callbacks
    bound(s): ActivityCallbacks
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends ActivityCallbacks declared in method <T>asCallbacks(Activity,Class<T>)
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2 errors
:compileDebugJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

The problematic source file is:

```
package org.drzewo.openmrs.android.andromeda.dialog;

import java.util.Calendar;

import org.drzewo.openmrs.android.andromeda.R;
import org.drzewo.openmrs.android.andromeda.dialog.DateTimePickerActivity.PickerOptions;
import org.drzewo.openmrs.android.andromeda.event.OnDateTimeSelected;
import org.drzewo.openmrs.android.andromeda.util.ActivityCallbacks;
import org.drzewo.openmrs.android.andromeda.util.Util;

import roboguice.event.EventManager;
import roboguice.fragment.RoboFragment;
import roboguice.inject.InjectView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import com.google.inject.Inject;

public class DateTimeFragment extends RoboFragment implements OnClickListener {

    @Inject
    private EventManager mEventManager;

    @InjectView(R.id.date)
    private DatePicker mDate;

    @InjectView(R.id.time)
    private TimePicker mTime;

    @InjectView(R.id.ok_button)
    private Button mOkButton;

    private PickerOptions mPickerOptions;

    public DateTimeFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mPickerOptions = Util.asCallbacks(activity, Callbacks.class).getPickerOptions();
        if (mPickerOptions == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No picker options provided");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_date_time, container, false);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("incomplete-switch")
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        switch (mPickerOptions) {
        case DATE:
            mTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case TIME:
            mDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mTime.setIs24HourView(true);
            break;
        }
        mOkButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mOkButton == v) {
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            switch (mPickerOptions) {
            case DATE:
                calendar.set(mDate.getYear(), mDate.getMonth(), mDate.getDayOfMonth());
                break;
            case TIME:
                calendar.set(0, 0, 0, mTime.getCurrentHour(), mTime.getCurrentMinute());
                break;
            case DATE_TIME:
                calendar.set(mDate.getYear(), mDate.getMonth(), mDate.getDayOfMonth(),
                        mTime.getCurrentHour(), mTime.getCurrentMinute());
                break;
            }
            mEventManager.fire(new OnDateTimeSelected(calendar.getTime()));
        }
    }

    public interface Callbacks extends ActivityCallbacks {
        PickerOptions getPickerOptions();
    }
}
```

It looks like the

```
import org.drzewo.openmrs.android.andromeda.util.ActivityCallbacks;
```

line does not do its job properly, but If I change the

```
public interface Callbacks extends ActivityCallbacks {
```

line to

```
public interface Callbacks extends org.drzewo.openmrs.android.andromeda.util.ActivityCallbacks {
```

then everything works fine.

So I know the workaround, but just don't want to apply it without understanding what is the root of the problem. The import line is valid, exactly the same solution in few other files does not cause any errors. When I use Eclipse instead of Gradle to build the project, everything works just fine.

This is my build.gradle script:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.xtend:xtend-gradle-plugin:0.1.+'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'xtend-android'
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

group = projectGroup
version = projectVersion

sourceCompatibility = 1.6
targetCompatibility = 1.6

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.eclipse.xtend:org.eclipse.xtend.lib:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    compile 'org.drzewo.openmrs:jomrsa:0.8.0'
    compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:2.0'
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.8'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            resources {
                exclude '**/*.xtend'
            }
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        debug.setRoot('build-types' + File.separator + 'debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types' + File.separator + 'release')
    }

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

eclipse {
    project {
        name = rootProject.name

        buildCommands = [
            'org.eclipse.xtext.ui.shared.xtextBuilder',
            'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder',
            'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder',
            'org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder',
            'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder'
        ]

        natures = [
            'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.nature',
            'org.eclipse.xtext.ui.shared.xtextNature',
            'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature',
            'org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature'
        ]
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.12'
}

apply from: 'gradle' + File.separator + 'copyLibs.gradle'
```

So the question is: why do I experience this problem and how should I fix it?

PS. In case someone would like to compile the above project: it is hosted in Fossil repository [here](https://drzewo.org/andromeda), and the project it depends on is [here](https://drzewo.org/jomrsa) (in Fossil repository as well). The server uses self-signed certificate, so browsers may complain about it.

Answer (score 0):

As I remember, it was about missing `build.gradle` for one of modules.